# "Super-Meta" Call for requests for U&L site customizations

Tags: discussion, design, user-interface

No, this isn't about an Emacs key combination!

I happened to catch [Responsive Design Themes - What can sites customize and how can they get changes implemented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319274/responsive-design-themes-what-can-sites-customize-and-how-can-they-get-changes) on Meta Stack Exchange where there was an invitation for each site to discuss their site's design elements in order to:

> better reflect their communities and allow them to be different from the rest of the network

Given the recent changes announced in 
[Unix & Linux new site theme is live](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4923/unix-linux-new-site-theme-is-live), I thought I'd post this question here as a "bridge" to start any discussions relating to our site.

If you would like to see a change in any of the below elements (transcribed from the MSE post above), then create a new Meta post, tagged [design](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design), relating specifically to that element.

Site-customizable elements at this point are:

- background -- currently a grid of dots (I think)
- header content -- [recently decided to be blank](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4945/what-should-our-sites-header-graphic-be)
- logo -- currently the [UNIX & LINUX graphic](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/unix/img/logo.svg?v=eb6eb2b9e73c)
- photo box -- currently none
- footer -- currently "Linux is a registered trademark..." (I think)
- sidebar -- currently stock (I think); "could be light-colored solid, pattern/texture, or fade or even a combination."
- the colors of:

  - Buttons (voting/accept/favorite/Ask Question/Review’s Leave Open, Skip, etc/, I think?)
  - OP indicator boxes (background shading of OP’s name on their comments on their own post)
  - link colors (visited/unvisited)
  - voting arrow colors
  - tag colors (background & text)
  - question titles (in the questions list, not on question pages)

Please feel free to clarify any point above, as I have no better insight to the site's design elements than any other user.

Comment: I liked previous design better (without left sidebar). Also generally colors should be a bit darker for my taste. Here is old related (in one small bit) question: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/icons-of-the-badge-counts

Comment: Reviewing the list again, I don't see anything I'm itching to change. It's unfortunate that [badge icons](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/icons-of-the-badge-counts?noredirect=1&lq=1) are missing from the list -- that's something I'd like to see here.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I have been bothered by the logo on the app for a while and think it should be addressed.

[image]

Comment: I honestly don't know if that's "covered" by the redesign team or by the android-app / ios-app team. I'd recommend posting that on Meta Stack Exchange with one of those -app tags and the "design" tag to get the right person's attention

Comment: Nothing's going to change on the apps; they stopped development on it.

Comment: @muru that logo is probably loaded from an API though, right?